# Relative to absolute: get the position that a relatively positioned element would have if it was absolutely positioned?

Tags: javascript, positioning

I am wondering if there is a way to get the "absolute position" of an element that is relatively positioned. I can't think of any, but maybe someone figured out a method...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "absolute position," but you can get the client coordinates of an element with `el.getBoundingClientRect()`

Comment: The position that a relatively positioned element would have if it was absolutely positioned.

Comment: To clarify, relative position is the same as static, as far as the individual element is concerned.  In terms of calculation, this is the job of a web client, so I recommend, if possible, actually adding it to the DOM (invisibly if needed) and setting a timeout so that you can calculate the position of the element after the web client has repositioned it.

Comment: Er... not sure what this is going to do? I want to know the position (absolute offset) of a relatively positioned element as if it was absolutely positioned.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like this question needs more details.

They should technically both have the same xy position, the only difference is that the relatively-positioned element should have a "footprint" of wherever it was moved from, and the absolutely-positioned element shouldn't leave any "footprint".

Comment: I know. I am interested in knowing the position that a relatively positioned element would have if it was absolutely positioned. (but in the same place)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution, but it might require a great deal of work to implement.

We know that internally, the rendering engine of any browser knows exactly where each element is positioned. If just the positioning code could be extracted and made into a plugin, we could then know the screen bounds (absolute position) of every relatively positioned element. Perhaps something similar to html2canvas...